# RecyclerView implement GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

### Problem

I want to use `RecyclerView` to implement `GridView`.In fact I need to display all local photos in `RecyclerView` which has 3 columns.I know about `GridLayoutManager`

My code :

```
   mManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
```

And the item `XML`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

however how can I set the item view (`ImageView`)'s width and height?

### Solution

I define a custom view:

```
public class RatioImageView extends ImageView {

    private int originalWidth;
    private int originalHeight;


   public RatioImageView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }


   public RatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
   }   


    public RatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }


   public void setOriginalSize(int originalWidth, int originalHeight) {
       this.originalWidth = originalWidth;
       this.originalHeight = originalHeight;
   }


    @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       if (originalWidth > 0 && originalHeight > 0) {
           float ratio = (float) originalWidth / (float) originalHeight;

           int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
           int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

      
           if (width > 0) {
               height = (int) ((float) width / ratio);
           }

           setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
       }
       else {
           super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
       }
   }
}
```

### Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating `Custom ImageView` when you are creating your `view` inside `onCreateViewHolder()` method by inflating your recycler item `view`, you can set width and height to your `ImageView` using layoutParamas.

If you want 3 columns then you can get screen width and divide it into 3 and pass that to your `RecyclerView Adapter` and use it in `onCreateViewHolder()` to apply.